# How do I update an existing entry in my database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How can I update my database properly? I'd like to modify an entry for which I have the id for, but a 'net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' is returned. Below I have my Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $booking = Booking::query($id);
        $booking->start_date = $request->start;
        $booking->end_date = $request->end;
        $booking->save();
        return response()->json($booking);
    }
```

These are all defined in my home blade view:

```
      const eventData = {
        id: eventid,
        start: arg.event.start.toISOString(),
        end: arg.event.end.toISOString(),
      };
```

How do I properly update start_date and end_date in my database?

Additionally, this is my Javascript used to fetch:

```
      const eventid = arg.event.id;
      const eventData = {
        start: arg.event.start.toISOString(),
        end: arg.event.end.toISOString(),
      };
      const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;
      console.log(csrfToken);
      fetch(`/api/event/update/${eventid}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
        },
        body: encodeFormData(eventData),
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      console.log("Complete");
```

Comment: Put code into try/catch block and read error message what says.

Comment: Nothing is outputted unforunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're passing the ID for the booking, but from what I can see on the above, the ID is being passed in the request. Try this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($request->id);
        $booking->start_date = $request->start;
        $booking->end_date = $request->end;
        $booking->save();

        return response()->json($booking);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work, rather I am getting an error now that states: PUT 405 (Method not allowed)

Comment: @Miggle in your routes file, what is the URL you're fetching set to? for example is it 'Route::post'?

Answer (score 0):

Updating a record is straight forward all you've got to is

```php
public function update(Request $request)
    {
// find the record by it's ID and also update it on the fly if you don't need to process anything else
     $updatedData = Booking::findOrFail($request->id)->update(['start_date' => $request->start, 'end_date' => $request->end]);

     return response()->json($updatedData);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this also seems to fix the empty response error, rather I am now getting a 'PUT 405 (Method not allowed)' instead.

Comment: Yeah no problem, that is a route problem check if your route is the correct type eg. POST, GET. YOU GOT THIS!, happy coding.